# WinForms XtraGrid column filter checked listbox actual data

Tags: c#, filter, devexpress, xtragrid

Y've already helped me a lot. But I have another trouble.
I have an XtraGrid with data. Two columns configured to show checked list box for filtering. For example one column for States and other for Cities. This listboxes contains column data, so user can check multiple values and grid will ilter up its view.
But when you choose filter in first column (for example one State) and then open second column filter its listbox contains all data (with all available Cities, but not the Cities from filtered State) from grid but not from currently filtered view.

Is there any method to update filter checkedlistbox to show only currenlty visible values for column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve such functionality by setting `ShowAllTableValuesInCheckedFilterPopup` to false. 
More on the subject here: https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnViewOptionsFilter_ShowAllTableValuesInCheckedFilterPopuptopic

[image: Where to find the option]

Comment: As I figured from your link to DevEx documentation this options exists in DevEx v 14.1. But I have only 10.1 and I think there is no such option. So sad.

Comment: Also Exists in 13.2 and (shold be) in lower versions too. See my edited answer.

Comment: And here is my (10.1) designer http://i60.tinypic.com/noby83.png Anyway thank you for your answer, maybe someday I will buy newer version of this tools.